# Installing Flash Player for Safari in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, adobe-flash, wine

I have installed Safari browser in Ubuntu 10.10 using Wine tricks. Now I wish to run a website which has Flash content. I am trying to install Adobe Flash but it is not working even though Flash is already installed in Ubuntu.

Is there any work-around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flash plugin you have installed is the Linux one. The Safari browser you are running is inside of a windows-look-alike environment bubble, and would need a windows version of the flash plugin installed inside the same environment. I don't think Flash under WINE will help you much with Safari. [It is listed](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=14658) with "Bronze" level support on the WineHQ site but the install needs a work-around, only the Opera plugin part actually works, and the various issues seem to be legion.

I would suggest that if so desperately need to run Safari for some reason (testing for example), you should do it inside a virtual machine running Windows using VirtualBox. This will provide you with a clean real Windows environment and allow you to run things like plugins. Safari under WINE might run as a browser but it will never be a fair way to evaluate it's functionality or test sites with it.